# Paperclip - No route matches GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, routes, paperclip

Paperclip 2.7
Ruby 1.8.7 Enterprise
Rails 3.1.0
Imagemagick 6.6

When i upload an image im my app, they are correctly processed by imagemagick and they are stored in conrrectly path. But, when i need to take this file to show, is not found.

**Saving image:**

```
Started POST "/p" for 177.16.57.105 at Sun Sep 23 23:39:16 -0300 2012
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Salvar", "authenticity_token"=>"EgBUGfKIIduS2lkl0mh5p27pT0vF0/P8HXO852KHMM8=", "utf8"=>"â", "product"=>{"photo"=>#>, "price"=>"", "name"=>"Brigadeiro de pistache", "product_type"=>"1", "featured"=>"0", "description"=>"Brigadeiro de pistache"}}
[32mCommand[0m :: convert '/tmp/stream20120923-19588-vw8u1s-020120923-19588-3lym39-0[0]' -resize "120x80>" '/tmp/stream20120923-19588-vw8u1s-020120923-19588-3lym39-020120923-19588-16ky3i8-0'
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] saving /home/brigaderiagourmand/apps_rails/site/public/system/photos/24/short/brigadeirocolorido.png
Redirected to http://brigaderiagourmand.com.br/p/24
Completed 302 Found in 257ms
```

**And when i need take the file...**

```
Started GET "/photos/original/missing.png" for 177.16.57.105 at Sun Sep 23 23:39:17 -0300 2012

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/photos/original/missing.png"):
```

**My model**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :price, :photo, :product_type, :featured
  attr_accessor :photo_file_name
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :thumb => "50x50>", :medium => "280x180>", :large => "585x400>", :short => "120x80>", :original => "200,200>" }

  TYPES = ["Belga", "Normal"]
end
```

**Form views**

```
= form_for @product, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
  = f.file_field :photo
```

**Show view**

```
= image_tag @product.photo.url(:original)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the output from processing the image complete?
In your output paperclip only re-sizes to short (120x80>)

Your get request is trying to load the missing.jpg which is a default for image if the the requested couldn't be found. Take a look into /home/brigaderiagourmand/apps_rails/site/public/system/photos/24/ and see if there are the other re-sized photos.

There is a great screencast from Ryan Bates about [paperclip](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip)

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks @Flo, but i migrate to carrierwave :)